# My manually created json.jbuilder files produce error, rails g jbuilder files do not, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

**Context:** 
Workstation is Widows 7, using Sublime Text3, Rails 4.1.7

I aimed to build my first API, and found Matthew Sullivan's blog post at https://codelation.com/blog/rails-restful-api-just-add-water. More specifically I followed Beryllium's post at http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2014/09/rails-and-angular-data.html which is verbatim Matt's post with the exception of an added option to the routes setting a default parameter for the format, and different model names.

I followed both posts to the letter, and the api calls worked correctly, json output shows in the browser.

I then applied the same modules to one of my on-going projects. Calling the API produced the error message

> undefined local variable or method `json' line#1 of the index.json.jbuilder file

I tried to trace down the cause of the error and did the following:

1. looked through all lines of code in the modules/controllers, and view .json.jbuilder files, corrected any mistakes, **error message persists**
2. called the index.json.jbuilder and show.json.jbuilder that is created by scaffold, **no error message**, then called the api's separate index.json.jbuilder and show.json.jbuilder **error message returns** (*the problem must be the api's json.jbuilder files or something still in the modules*)
3. after more tinkering, searching stackoverflow for an answer and creating a few more new projects to test (all which did NOT display error message), I "saved as.." every api file in my project as UTF-8 just to be sure. **error message persists**
4. I had created the api's json files using the 'new file' from Sublime Text3, then 'saved as..' into my project (UTF-8). So, I decided to delete the api's index.json.jbuilder and show.json.jbuilder files, and replace them using 'rails generator jbuilder' **no more error message**

**Question:** Why would this error message occur and this fix rectify it? I assumed it was a problem with rails, my code, but now it seems the actual files, or maybe even my own box.